Invalid YaraSharp library in C#
When i run the code below that error appears.
using YaraSharp;
YSInstance YSInstance = new YSInstance();


System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
'YaraSharp, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
file or assembly 'YaraSharp, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library
(.dll) is invalid. File name: 'YaraSharp, Version=1.3.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'    at Program.$(String[]
args)

If you guys can find a solution to it.
I tried reinstalling and it didn't work. I don't know how to fix it.

What .NET version are you targeting?

Could be because of the architecture of the assembly you using (32-bit vs. 64-bit)
